# Maven SoapUI plugin, testing for missing path parameters

Tags: maven-2, soapui, regression-testing

I have some regression tests for a web service to make sure we return errors when required fields are missing. When query parameters (e.g. http://dummyurl.com?someRequiredParameter=something) are missing, everything works fine. When required path parameters are missing (e.g. http://dummyurl.com/requiredPathParameter/somethingelse), the test works correctly in the SoapUI application, but fails when run from Maven. I see errors in the output when it tries to query these bad URLs, but is there something different about the response (should I be checking for 500's from the server), or some other assertation I need to set up so the tests pass in both SoapUI and Maven?

**EDIT**

The full error is:

```
16:07:38,672 ERROR [WsdlSubmit] Exception in request: org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: escaped absolute path not valid
16:07:38,672 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [escaped absolute path not valid], see error log for details
org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: escaped absolute path not valid
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.setRawPath(URI.java:2837)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.parseUriReference(URI.java:2023)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.<init>(URI.java:147)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getURI(HttpMethodBase.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:383)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:194)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:76)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRequest.submit(RestRequest.java:208)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep.run(RestTestRequestStep.java:753)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:207)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.internalRun(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:138)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.internalRun(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:39)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
16:07:38,673 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [Match content of [Fault]] has status UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for the test that fails?

Comment: I'll try to add the code later, VPNing from here pretty much destroys my ability to reach any host. But it's basically if (requiredPathParameter == null) { throw buildInformativeExceptionHere("Missing required parameter", parameter). The problem seems to be the fact the parameter in question is part of REST API call and is missing.

Comment: add -X to the maven line (debug), then look for the phase output

Comment: Where do I find the phase output? All I see is the same stack trace I added to the question a couple of days ago.

Comment: When you add the -X you enable the debug output, a very detailed and verbose output of maven execution. Assuming you are using maven version 3.0.x you should see a debug trace stating that the test, or integration-test phase is starting

Comment: I'm using maven 2, and all I can really see is the stack trace I pasted above. The plugin thinks the URL is malformed (which it is), and so nothing is being returned to validate against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately had to disable the tests in question. It appears the SoapUI application can handle missing path parameters but the maven plugin can't.

If a new answer pops up that explains how to test for this using the SoapUI maven plugin, I'll give it a try and (hopefully) make it the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour should be the same.

Check the log file generated by the SOAPUI Maven plugin. It contains for each test the return code. If there is an error on the server side, you should find 500's.

Your test case already contains an assertion checking the return code ?

Comment: There's no code in the error message though, it's just "ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [escaped absolute path not valid], see error log for details
org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: escaped absolute path not valid". I updated the question with the full stack trace. And yes, I'm already checking the return code.